# java8 class for composing file paths

Tags: java, file, path

I'm currently reworking some code of mine. This code looks currently *something like* this:

```
File makeFile() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append( "/" );

    if( a ) builder.append( foodir ).append( '/' );
    if( b ) builder.append( bardir ).append( '/' );

    builder.append( "file.txt" );

    return new File( b.toString() );
}
```

I really don't like this code very much because it uses `StringBuilder` to build something which should really be some kind of `Path` object in the first place.

So is there -- at least in Java8 -- some means of building `Path` or `File` objects in a more clean way?

(**Note**: I'm not looking for using `Collections` and later joining them. I'm looking for something working directly with filesystem objects.)

Comment: For starters, if you are using Java 8, this means you have java.nio.file available; which means you can use `Files` and `Paths`.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Look at the javadoc of File, and you'll find the constructors you're looking for. Look into the javadoc of Path, and you'll find a resolve() method.

Comment: use File.separator in place of "/" by the way.

Comment: I've seen `Files` and `Paths`. I found constructors like `Path p = Paths.get( String first, String ... more)` but I don't seem to find something like `p.append( "foodir" )` ...

Comment: The method is called resolve(), as already said. There are not many methods in Path. Take the time to read the javadoc. It's faster than asking a question here, and you might even learn new things by reading it.

Comment: @JB: I normally do. In this case I think I've overlooked it because I expected something differently (like `append`, `add` ...). Sometimes you need to know it's there to see it ...

Comment: Just to be sure: `Path p = Paths.get( "/" ); if( a ) p.resolve( "foodir" ); if( b ) p.resolve( "bardir" ); p.resolve( "file.txt" );` is the way to go? (Looks still strange in my eyes...) Does 'resolve' generate FS operations?

Comment: Again, read the javadoc. resolve() **returns** the new path. It doesn't alter the path on which the method is called.

Comment: @JB: You're right, sorry. Sloppy comment. Imagine some `p = ` in there and me asking the question again :)

Comment: What's the question exactly? The method does what it's documented to do. Test it, and you'll see. If the question is "do the files need to exist on the file system for that to work?", the answer is no. A Path is just that: a Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Paths javadoc:

```
Path p = Paths.get(String first, String... more)

Path p = Paths.get(URI uri)
```

Once you have your Path object you can just call the `resolve()` method with the next file extension. You should be careful using the "/" as that is platform dependent. Paths library will guarantee you platform independence